# Generating SSD from .NET Assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, c#-3.0

can anyone guide me on how to generate System Sequence Diagram from a .NET assembly file??? Has anyone done that before???

Comment: Try dragging the classes from the Object Browser, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this yet?  Someone asked the same question on another site a little over a year ago with a bunch of good responses.  Nothing that solves the issue fully, but a lot of good links for ideas and starting points.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxtoolsdev/thread/67b6904f-9d5f-479a-8a21-250a77e3fe19

The answer I tend to agree with the most from this forum is the following:

> To generate a sequence diagram, I
>   guess you need a profiler that can be
>   attached to a piece of ececuting code
>   to write the actual calling sequence
>   to an output file. It would be
>   particularly nice to have a tool that
>   could generate a sequence diagram from
>   a unit test.
>
> Perhaps this is a useful starting
>   point for such a tool:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dotnetprofiler.aspx

Comment: I've actually used Enterprise Architect ( http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/features.html ) to attach to a service and generate a sequence diagram.  It's not free but I was pretty impressed although there is some work in filtering the results to the correct granularity.